# Simplest way to generate doc for a nodejs module

Tags: node.js, documentation

I am finally documenting [Hotplate](https://github.com/mercmobily/hotplate). I really believe that documentation should [Teach, don't Tell](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2013/09/teach-dont-tell/) -- if you read the initial README.md in Hotplate you will see what I mean.

However, I do think I need some "telling" documentation (to be used as a quick reference once you've read the "Teaching" side of things) for Hotplate.

At the moment, I have this in my code:

```
/**
 * Load all modules that are marked as "enabled"
 *
 * This function will require and register all modules in modulesFullPath
 * that satisfy the `filter` regexp.
 * 
 * modulesFullPath is actually optional: when not there, it defaults
 * to the node_modules directory belonging to the current instante of Hotplate
 * 
 * @param {filter} The regexp which will filter the modules to load
 * @param {modulesFullPath} (optional) The full path of the modules to load
 *
 * @api public
 */
```

I copied this format from another NodeJS project.
Now, the question:

"What's the easiest possible way to turn something like this into actual documentation?"

Consider that:

- Hotplate is made up of multiple, small sub-modules.
- Each module has a server "main" file which does pretty much everything
- Each module defines one or more "hooks" which I would like to document (something like "List of implemented hooks)
- Each module can call several hooks, which I would like to document (something like "List of called hooks")

So, what's the easiest, sort-of automatic way to go about this?

Merc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[YUIdoc](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/) is very good at handling that style of remarks and generates very nice documentation from it.

Comment: The best I could find too. Not that I am 100% happy with it, but the best I could find.

Comment: I agree, it has some things I don't quite like much, but it still does a very good job.